# sign of eigenvalues of a positive Markov matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

can we find sign of eigenvalues of a positive Markov matrix? it is a large matric with real number elements?

Comment: As far as I know, nothing can be said in general. The only fact that could (maybe) tip a little the balance in favor of positive eigenvalues would be a relatively important trace of this matrix...